# Javascript splits unicode sentence into words

Tags: regex, unicode

I'm using following `regexp` for splitting sentence into words array.

```
/\b(?![\s.,:;'"])/
```

It works perfectly for non-unicode sentences, but fails in following sentence.

```
læseWEB læser teksten på dit website op.
```

I'm expecting

```
['læseWEB ', 'læser ', 'teksten ', 'på ', 'dit ', 'website ', 'op.'].
```

But I'm getting

```
['l', 'æ', 'se', 'WEB', 'l', 'æ', 'ser', 'teksten', 'p', 'å', 'dit','website', 'op']
```

I know javascript has issues in unicode manipulation.

I was going to use XRegExp javascript plugin, but I can't find an exact solution I'm looking for.

Comment: You are pointing to XRegExp, which is one possible approach, but you don’t show what you have actually tried and explain how it fails. Besides, you have not defined “word”. Your definition for “word” is *crucial* in issues like this. Is “中国” a word? Or is it two words?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The definition of`\b` in JavaScript is based on the definition of `\w`, which is `[A-Za-z0-9_]` (only covers ASCII characters).

If you use XRegExp with Unicode Category + Unicode Properties add-on, you can match (instead of splitting) the string with the following code:

```
XRegExp.matchChain("læseWEB læser teksten på dit website op.", [XRegExp("[\\p{Alphabetic}\\p{Nd}\\{Pc}\\p{M}]+", "g")])
>>> [ "læseWEB", "læser", "teksten", "på", "dit", "website", "op" ]
```

`[\\p{Alphabetic}\\p{Nd}\\{Pc}\\p{M}]` is an *incomplete* emulation of word character as suggested in the [annex C of UTS-18 Unicode Regular Expression](http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr18/#Compatibility_Properties). However, it should work for most purposes - it works even if the text uses combining marks instead of single glyph to represent a character.

If you don't want to load extra library, you can take a look at the XRegExp library and pull out the list of code points to build your own RegExp.

Comment: This works great. Would you help me with following? I want to get array of words with delimiters. Like [ "læseWEB ", "læser ", "teksten ", "på ", "dit ", "website ", "op." ]

Comment: @user3300990: Negate the regex above and use it as delimiter?

Comment: sorry, I'm so newbie to regex. Would you give me solution? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

`\b` is a word border; it matches a location in a string that has a "word character" (character matching `[0-9_a-zA-Z]`) on one side and a non-word character (`[^0-9_a-zA-Z]`) on the other side. `æ`, `å` and other characters like it are non technically word characters according to regex, so it can create a border to a word.

For more information see http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html.