# Splitting unicode sentence into words array using XRegExp

Tags: unicode, xregexp

I'm using following script for splitting Unicode sentence into words array.

```
XRegExp.matchChain("læseWEB læser teksten på dit website op.", [XRegExp("[\\p{Alphabetic}\\p{Nd}\\{Pc}\\p{M}]+", "g")])


[ "læseWEB", "læser", "teksten", "på", "dit", "website", "op" ]
```

Now I'm expecting

```
['læseWEB ', 'læser ', 'teksten ', 'på ', 'dit ', 'website ', 'op.'].
```

Someone said I need to use split function instead of matchChain.

Any suggestions?

Comment: This question looks remarkably similar to http://stackoverflow.com/q/27476745/139010

Comment: Yes, we are working on the same project and we are trying to solve this issue.

Comment: That question has an accepted answer. Does that solution work for you, or no?

Comment: Actually, I need to split the sentence into words with delimiter.

Comment: @AlanHaziq You're going to have to be clearer about why the answers to the other question don't work for you.

Comment: The answer on the similar question was splitting the sentence correctly, but each word does not contain the delimiter. I want to have the delimiter postfixed for each word.